# Using Kotlin standard library from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, kotlin, kotlin-js, kotlin-js-interop

I have a Kotlin function written that consumes a `List<String>`. The function has an annotation with `@JsName` so that I can call this function from JavaScript. I cannot determine though what I am supposed to pass into this function. Passing an JavaScript Array doesn't work because the Kotlin-JS code calls `iterator` on the object. Furthermore, the names in the Kotlin standard library are all mangled; so I cannot in any reliable way call say `listOf` in JavaScript and pass the results to function.

The question is then how beyond trivial types (numbers, string, etc.) are we supposed to create and pass to objects functions if the Kotlin standard library names are mangled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ArrayList when interop with JavaScript in Kotlin, since `List` is an interface (which isn't in JavaScript) and (one of) its actual implementation is `ArrayList`.

As you are dealing with `List<String>`, you may do this in JavaScript:

```
let list = new kotlin.kotlin.collections.ArrayList(["foo","bar","baz"])
```

And you can pass the `list` variable to the functions that needs a `List<String>` parameter.

Remarks:

1. You can call `list.toArray()` to convert a List from Kotlin back to JavaScript array, if some of your Kotlin functions returns a List.
2. I would declare "middleman" (adapter) functions that push an item to a `List`, that takes a `MutableList` and call `add`, since the library function is mangled. (I want a more proper way of doing this too)
3. If you need to deal with a List of custom objects, e.g. of class `Foo`, you should be able to call `new <package>.<identifier>...Foo(params)`.

Comment: Thank-you, I will look into this soon. I seem to remember all of the kotlin package names were mangled, but maybe there were some I did not notice. Is there some compiler flag you know of that is guaranteeing kotlin.kotlin.collections.* isn't mangled or are class names not mangled?

Comment: `kotlin.kotlin.collections.*` is from `kotlin.js` that is generated as a shared library along with the compiled Kotlin source. (I “require” it from NPM) Class names are not mangled but the function names are.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't sure how to convert from an ArrayList to a regular Javascript array. The `toArray()` did the trick!